# Asyncio Gathering a while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, python-requests, python-asyncio

This is a simplified version of my code, but the the problem is the same:

```
import asyncio

example = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

def test_1(numbers):
    while True:
        print(numbers)

tasks = []
async def test_2():
    for numbers in example:
        try:
            tasks.append(test_1(numbers))
        except:
            pass
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    except:
        pass

asyncio.run(test_2())
```

What I'm trying to do is printing all items at the same time in a while loop, but when I run the code it only prints the first item since it's looped, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: The function would need to `await` something somewhere to give a break and allow other code to run, or you'd need to *actually* run them in parallel using threading.

Comment: How can I thread the same function that uses different items? Should I use different arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it thanks to @deceze, I used threading in this way:

```
for numbers in example:
    t = threading.Thread(target=test_1, args=(numbers,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```